# How to get data after decoding from its encoded value?

Tags: php, json, base64, mcrypt, rijndael

I am doing a test of how to get actual data from encoded data using PHP-encoding functions. I can't get the original data once I encoded it. Instead I am getting some special [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters...

My code is as follows.

```
$key = '28e336ac6c9423d946ba02d19c6a2632'; // Randomly generated key
$request_params = array(
    'controller' => 'mylist',
    'action'     => 'read',
    'username'   => 'test',
    'password'   => '12345'
));
$enc_request = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, json_encode($request_params), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
//echo $enc_request;exit; // Here I am getting the encoded string.

$paramas = base64_decode(trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, json_decode($enc_request), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
print_r($paramas); // Here I am getting like ... ºÇ
echo $paramas->controller; // Got nothing.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in tst.php on line 8

Comment: Fixed that: Then : `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in tst.php on line 14`

Comment: when I tried only var_dump($paramas); it gets me... string(3) "ºÇ"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the order of operations you do. If you look closer at your code you are first JSON encoding, then encrypting and last [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. So to get back the original value you need to do it in the opposite order. First Base64 decode, then decrypt and last JSON decode. Try something like

```
$paramas = json_decode(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($enc_request), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

Also ECB mode should only be used for testing. Go for CBC if you are going to use this.

Also, mcrypt is depricated. You should check out openssl_ecrypt/openssl_decrypt instead. I don't have mcrypt installed, but this works using [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL):

```
$key = '28e336ac6c9423d946ba02d19c6a2632'; // Randomly generated key
$request_params = array(
    'controller' => 'mylist',
    'action'     => 'read',
    'username'   => 'test',
    'password'   => '12345'
);
$enc_request = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt(json_encode($request_params), 'AES-256-ECB', $key));
//echo $enc_request;exit; // Here I am getting the encoded string.

$paramas = json_decode(openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($enc_request), 'AES-256-ECB', $key));
print_r($paramas); // Here I am getting like ... ºÇ
echo $paramas->controller;
```

Comment: Correct the order is wrong, but I am testing what I believe is the correct order and I get a json_decode error `Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded` even then

Comment: Try to echo the text before json_decode, it should be a readable string

Answer (score 1):

When you do thing in the correct order it works.

This code I have tested and it does work

```
<?php

$key = '28e336ac6c9423d946ba02d19c6a2632';//randomly generated key
$request_params = array(
    'controller' => 'mylist',
    'action'     => 'read',
    'username'   => 'test',
    'password'   => '12345'
);
$js = json_encode($request_params);
$encd = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $js, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

$enc_request = base64_encode($encd);
echo $enc_request . PHP_EOL;

// now reverse process in correct order
$one   = base64_decode($enc_request);
$two   = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $one, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$twoa  = trim($two);
echo $twoa . PHP_EOL;

$three = json_decode($twoa);

print_r($three);
echo $three->controller . PHP_EOL;
```

It also works with the `openssl` functions suggested by @rypskar

```
<?php

$key = '28e336ac6c9423d946ba02d19c6a2632';//randomly generated key
$request_params = array(
    'controller' => 'mylist',
    'action'     => 'read',
    'username'   => 'test',
    'password'   => '12345'
);
$js = json_encode($request_params);
//$encd = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $js, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$encd = openssl_encrypt($js, 'AES-256-ECB', $key);

$enc_request = base64_encode($encd);
echo $enc_request . PHP_EOL;

// now reverse process in correct order
$one   = base64_decode($enc_request);
//$two   = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $one, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$two   = openssl_decrypt($one, 'AES-256-ECB', $key);
$twoa  = trim($two);
echo $twoa . PHP_EOL;
$three = json_decode($twoa);

print_r($three);
echo $three->controller . PHP_EOL;
```